# sudo permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian

I ran this code:

```
sudo cat <<EOF | sudo sed -e "s,%,$,g" >/etc/init.d/dropbox
  echo "Hello World"
EOF
```

But even though, I get "permission denied", cause you have to be root to make changes in the /etc/init.d directory. And somehow, my command above doesn't work.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

**The redirection to a file is handled by bash. It does therefore not inherit permissions granted by sudo.**

Use `sudo tee` for writing to a file as root.

Try this:

```
cat | sed -e 's,%,$,g' | sudo tee /etc/init.d/dropbox << EOF
  echo "Hello World"
EOF
```

Notice that `$,` inside double quotes might be interpreted.

Comment: It still gives me "Permission denied".

Comment: I have edited the answer. use sudo tee rather.

Answer (score 5):

You could grant yourself persistent su-rights with
`# sudo -s`

then your command (do not need to sudo anymore) and exit with
`# exit`

EDIT:
I assume you're asking Ubuntu-related because your question is tagged with that. In other distribution like Suse you'll have the ability to use
`# su`
instead of `# sudo -s`

Comment: Or get persistent su-rights with just `su`.

Comment: @Chetan: This does not work in Ubuntu. (The question is tagged with Ubuntu, so I expect that it was in this consense)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that this is in a script so I can't do sudo to run it.

Comment: If its in a script you could start the script with sudo as far as I know: `# sudo ./myScript`

Comment: But since it's a script I cannot use sudo -s inside the script cause the lines after it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

This part: `sudo sed -e "s,%,$,g" >/etc/init.d/dropbox` cen be viewed as this:

```
sudo somecommand --put the result of the sudo command into--> /etc/init.d/dropbox
```

In the same way as this:

```
ls somedirectory > filename
ls somedirectory --put the result of the ls command into--> filename
```

This means that the file writing will be done as your current user, not as root.

You can solve it by using `tee` as Benoit shows in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the description of the problem. But how do I solve it?